# how about the ModSecurity Dos Protection?

Tags: nginx, mod-security

i try to install the modsecurity 2.9.1, but it seemed not working for dos protection,i test by ab tools, test like below:

> ab -r -k -n50 -c20 -H "User-Agent: test by George" "http://api.domain.com/test/ab?k1=v10"

but the result:

```
Document Path:          /test/ab?k1=v10
Document Length:        0 bytes

Concurrency Level:      20
Time taken for tests:   6.202 seconds
Complete requests:      50
Failed requests:        0
Keep-Alive requests:    0
Total transferred:      0 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    8.06 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2480.740 [ms] (mean)
```

There is no effect under concurrency. my modsecurity config like below:

```
setvar:'tx.static_extensions=/.jpg/ /.jpeg/ /.png/ /.gif/ /.js/ /.css/ /.ico/',\
setvar:'tx.dos_burst_time_slice=5',\
setvar:'tx.dos_counter_threshold=20',\
setvar:'tx.dos_block_timeout=120'"
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What is your Core Rule Set / CRS version? (The DOS rules you are using are taken from the CRS)

Comment: OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set ver.3.0.2, from v3.0/master,does it matter?

Comment: The rules were overhauled for 3.0.0, and I wanted to be sure you were covered.

The rules work for me - also with you setvars. However, your ab does not call nearly enough to be considered a ddos attack. It is worthwhile to read the documentation within the rule file carefully.
Hint: You need to meet the threshold twice in paranoia level 1.

Comment: @dune73 I too am not able to trip DOS protection using the same settings. Even when setting the paranoia level to 4.

Comment: PL 2 should be enough (hitting the threshold once will lead to blocking). The ab call above was not nearly aggressive enough. But raising n should work.